# Kubernetes - How to create a service that point to LAN application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

My infrastructure is based on Kubernetes (k3s, with istio ingress). I would like to use istio to expose an application that is not in my cluster.

outside (internet) --https--> my router --> [cluster] istio --> [not cluster] application (192.168.1.29:8123)

I tried creating a HAProxy container, but it didn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on piping your traffic to the non-cluster application through the Kubernetes cluster, there are a couple of ways to handle this. You could use a Kubernetes-native [`ExternalName` Kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname).

The Istio way would be to create a [`ServiceEntry`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry), though, and then use a `VirtualService` combined with a `Gateway` to direct traffic to your application outside of the cluster.